# Alternative of Dictionary<String,Any>?

Tags: swift, swift3

I know that my Dictionary will be either `<String,String>` or it will be `<String,NSNumber>` , Is there any way i can tell this to Swift compiler at the declaration time , rather than declaring `<String,Any>` or `<String,AnyObject>` ?

Comment: I think that why `Any` and `AnyObject` are helpful for.

Comment: Are you declaring a function parameter `func f(a: [String: String] | [String: NSNumber])`, return value `func f() -> [String: String] | [String: NSNumber]` or something else?

Comment: `[String:Any]` is the way to go, maybe declaring generic can help but I think its more useful for function param since they can accept protocol also

Comment: i want to use some more specific declaration if possible....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an empty protocol and make String and NSNumber conform to it.

```
protocol StringOrNumber {}

extension String:StringOrNumber {}
extension NSNumber:StringOrNumber {}
```

It might help to explicitly add Int, Float and Double

```
extension Int:StringOrNumber {}
extension Float:StringOrNumber {}
extension Double:StringOrNumber {}
```

Then you can create a dictionary with strings and numbers

```
var dict:[String:StringOrNumber] = ["a":1, "b": 3.2,"c": "c"]

dict["d"] = "a string"
dict["e"] = 1.3
```

But you can't add things that are not strings or numbers

```
dict["f"] = Date() //error: Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'StringOrNumber?'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enum Either<L, R> {
    case left(L)
    case right(R)

    init(_ left: L) {
        self = .left(left)
    }

    init(_ right: R) {
        self = .right(right)
    }

    init?(_ any: Any) {
        if let left = any as? L {
            self = .left(left)
        } else if let right = any as? R {
            self = .right(right)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And then declare your dictionary as `<String, Either<String, NSNumber>>`.

Or if you're fan of hardcoding types:

```
enum StringOrNumber {
    case string(String)
    case number(NSNumber)

    init(string: String) {
        self = .string(string)
    }

    init(number: NSNumber) {
        self = .number(number)
    }

    init?(any: Any) {
        if let string = any as? String {
            self = .string(string)
        } else if let number = any as? NSNumber {
            self = .number(number)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And dictionary would be `<String, StringOrNumber>`

**EDIT**: If your dictionary itself can only contain either **all** `String`s or **all** `NSNumber`s as value, type should be `Either<[String: String], [String: NSNumber]>`

Comment: The problem with this is that he still can't declare `var stringOrNumberDict: [String : Either<String, Int>] = ["A": 1, "B": "two"]` he has to use `["A": Either(1), "B": Either("two")]`. Good effort, though!

Comment: @Grimxn, why would you hide `init?(:Any)`? It's for case when you have an `[Any]` with `Strings`/`NSNumber` and you `map` over it to get array of either-enum.

Comment: OK. For purity! But if init with `[Any]` is needed, then go for it! Or have a factory `static func fromAny(_: [Any]) -> [Either]`. I try to hide failable inits from my interfaces if at all possible...

Comment: @Grimxn, can you elaborate? What's so dangerous in `(Any) -> T?` function?

Comment: Notwithstanding your `[Any]` case (which is an extension to the basic struct) your failable init is an internal mechanism which will only ever be called (by your public inits) with an `L` or an `R` and will therefore never actually fail. By making it public you allow other developers to call it with another type entirely - and that's their problem, not yours, for sure - but it just gives another opportunity for someone to wrongly use a force-unwrapping (and goodness knows we see enough of those round here!)

Comment: @Grimxn, even if i remove `init?` they still can do someting like `init(any as! L)`, and here you go, you now have same problem with force unwrapping. If someone would like to shoot in own leg it would be still possible. But yeah all those `init` are there only for sugar actually, if you don't like you can init it with `case`s.

Comment: Alternatively - "Write everything as if you are creating a library to be used by fools. Even if you are not writing a library, one day that fool will be you." :)

Comment: This is good effort. but what if that dictionary comes as server JSON response ?

Comment: @mihirmehta, `map` over it, depending how it comes

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on `user28434`'s answer, you could mimic the C union type behavior since it serves the "either or" situation best and has mutually exclusive cases.

The Swift implementation of a union might look ugly though:

```
enum StringOrNum {
    case a(String)
    case b(NSNumber)

    var a: String {
        switch(self)
        {
        case .a(let stringValue): return stringValue
        case .b(let nsnumberValue): return String(format:"%f", nsnumberValue.doubleValue)
        }
    }

    var b: NSNumber {
        switch(self)
        {
        case .a(let stringValue): if let intValue = Int(stringValue) {
                                      return NSNumber(value: intValue)
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      return NSNumber(value: 0)    // default case
                                  }
        case .b(let nsnumberValue): return nsnumberValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then declare the dictionary as `Dictionary<String, StringOrNum>`

Answer (score -1):

Can this will help you?

```
func myFoo<T>(dic: [String: T]) {

    if dic["Key"] is String {
        print("The value is String --> \(dic["Key"])")
    }

    if dic["Key"] is Int {
        print("The value is Int --> \(dic["Key"])")
    }
}

myFoo(dic: ["Key": 0])
myFoo(dic: ["Key": "Value"])
```